# Can't get celery to run in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, celery

I am unable to get celery to run in docker. Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  django:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 
    volumes: 
      - ./:/YTAPI/
    ports: 
      - 8000:8000
    env_file: 
      - .env
    depends_on: 
      - mongodb
      - redis

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    volumes: 
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
    ports: 
      - 27017:27017

  celery:
    build: .
    command: 
      - celery -A YTapi beat -l INFO
    volumes:
      - celery-data:/data/celery-data/
    
    depends_on: 
      - django
      - redis
      - mongodb
  
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"


volumes: 
  mongodb-data:
  celery-data:
```

And this is the Dockerfile in the same directory:

```
FROM python:3.6.13

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y ${BUILD_DEPS} ${APP_DEPS} --no-install-recommends \
  && pip install -r requirements.txt \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && rm -rf /usr/share/doc && rm -rf /usr/share/man \
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove ${BUILD_DEPS} \
  && apt-get clean

COPY . .
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d --build`, it shows me the following error:

```
ERROR: for aea25712da4c_ytapi_celery_1  Cannot start service celery: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "celery -A YTapi beat -l INFO": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

ERROR: for celery  Cannot start service celery: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "celery -A YTapi beat -l INFO": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

I have celery in my requirements.txt file and when I try to access celery from my django container, I am not facing any problems.

**Edit** - I just replaced `- celery -A YTapi beat -l INFO` with `['celery', '-A', 'YTapi', 'beat', '-l', 'INFO']` and it is working now.

Comment: `command: celery -A YTapi beat -l INFO` <= note the string type **not list**. If you want to provide a list you need to seperate each element of the command in its own item, e.g. `['celery', '-A', 'YTapi', 'beat', '-l', 'INFO']`

Comment: @Zeitounator It is working now. Thanks.